# control does not exist in the current context in master page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have a web project in asp.net
I have a Master page that contains a link button that called `lkBtnUserFullName`, but I can't access to this control in the `Page_Load` in `Masterpage.master.cs`
when I manually access to this control, I will have an error:

> the name lkBtnUserFullName does not exists in current context

how can I solve this?

**Update:**

my code:

```
<asp:LinkButton ToolTip="Please Click Here!" 
 ID="lkBtnUserFullName" PostBackUrl="~/admins/profile.aspx" 
  runat="server">Majid Basirati</asp:LinkButton></span>
```

in `Page_Load` of `MasterPage.master.cs` :

```
lkBtnUserFullName.Text = Session["fullname"].ToString();
```

Comment: did you add `runat="server"` to linkbutton?

Comment: Are you sure the control is present their on masterpage,
By looking at error seem the you have **deleted** that contorl or it may have different **id**

Comment: `<asp:LinkButton ID="lkBtnUserFullName" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>` . It is correct code. If doesn't work, post your code.

Comment: @rs. yes, this control has `runat="server"`

Comment: @MajidBasirati can you post your aspx markup then?

Comment: @satindersingh : yes. I sure

Comment: My code is added! Please see my question again

Answer (score 2):

Right click on your master page file in Solution Explorer and select **Convert to Web Application** it will regenerate the .designer file for you and you will once again be able to access all the master page server controls from code behind

Comment: I don't find **Convert to Web Application** in Right Click menu!

Comment: Is this a web site or a web application?

Comment: Yes, This is a Web Application.

Comment: Could you please post the complete .aspx code for your master page?I want to see exactly where the lkBtnUserFullName is located in the designer

Comment: The .aspx mark up appears to be valid, could you please try deleting the master page from the project and re-creating it?

Comment: I save my master page code and deleted this then re-create it and paste my code on this. but my problem wasn't solved

Comment: fixed our project (converted from asp.net website to web application) because of this answer. 

Thanks @Deni

Answer (score 0):

That looks like Visual Studio synchronizing with designer issue. I had this several times. Usually I try following:

Remove all the server controls from your aspx that are not present in designer.cs file (controls that are out of sync). Then remove in code behind to get successful build, save everything and restart your Visual Studio.

Try again, it should work.

Comment: Thanks dear. where is designer.cs? I don't find that in solution explorer. notify my problem is in the MasterPage

Comment: Well you have master page. It contains of 3 files: aspx, cs and designer.cs. Designer file is generated automatically by Visual Studio but normally you shouldn't edit it. Though sometimes it is not synchronized well with aspx file and thats why you have to do steps like this.

Comment: OK. but you didn't tell me: where is designer.cs file. I don't find in solution explorer.

Comment: I don't know what is the name of you master page. Let it be Default.Master. Find you Default.Master in solution explorer and expand it. You will see 2 related files under it. Those would be Default.Master.cs and Default.Master.designer.cs

Comment: But I don't see designer.cs under of Master. I only have Master.cs

Comment: Hmm, that may be the problem.
Copy your code from master page to safe place, then remove it and add new clean master page. Please look if this new one will have designer.cs file. Then copy your code back.

Comment: I must tell you, any file in solution explorer (.aspx or master) doesn't have desinger.cs, but my project works correctly except this problem that I explain in up.

Comment: I am not sure, maybe those files are hidden in VS 2012.
What if you take any server control (declared on markup page) in code-behind and press F12 (Go to definition), it should navigate you to designer.cs file.

Comment: Also take a look at following link. This issue is very similar to what you have and thats why I told you about that. But their resolution does not work always.
http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2010/02/08/ASPNET-Regenerate-designercs.aspx

Comment: when I press F12, an error was shown:Cannot navigate to definition

Answer (score 0):

create a new Default.Desiginer.cs file by your own in the current master page and create a partial class like this.

```
public partial class Site_Master {

    /// <summary>
    /// form1 control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Auto-generated field.
    /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    /// </remarks>
    protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm form1;

    /// <summary>
    /// ContentPlaceHolder1 control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Auto-generated field.
    /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    /// </remarks>
    /// 
    protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblName;

    /// <summary>
    /// btnSearchEmp control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Auto-generated field.
    /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    /// </remarks>
    /// 

    protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblBranch;

    /// <summary>
    /// btnSearchEmp control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Auto-generated field.
    /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    /// </remarks>
    protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.ContentPlaceHolder ContentPlaceHolder1;
}
```

and in your master aspx file add this line 
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Site_Master" %> 
Inherits="Site_Master" is the class name you have created . then you will be able to access the Controles in your .cs file .